# Pytest Django Discovers Fixture but Says "Not Found" on the Run

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-django

I have a project where each app has a `tests` module as below:

```
app1/
  tests/
    __init__.py
    # whatever test files are
app2/
  tests/
    __init__.py
    # whatever test files are
```

And also have the project package in the project root as you can guess. It has a `testing` subpackage, which contains base test cases for models and fields and, of course, fixtures as below:

```
myproject/
  __init__.py
  # settings and related files, you know
  testing/
    __init__.py
    fixtures.py  # for fixtures
    # other modules for base test classes and stuff
```

So, my overall project structure is:

```
myproject/  # contains standard django stuff and a testing subpackage
app1/  # contains app and tests
app2/  # so as above
# so on and so forth
```

And the `pytest.ini` content in project root is as below:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = myproject.settings.development
python_files =
    test_*.py
    myproject/testing/fixtures.py
addopts = -s
console_output_style = count
log_cli_level = DEBUG
log_print = True
```

So, assuming `myproject/testing/fixtures.py` contains a fixture as below:

```py
# assuming i've imported related stuff

@pytest.fixture  # might have different scope
def foo():
    """does foo"""
    return "foo"
```

And later on, I do `pytest --fixtures` to see if pytest properly discovers my fixture and so it does, which means there should not be a problem.

However, when I run tests in the project, I get the error below:

```
E       fixture 'foo' not found
```

This is odd since I can clearly see it in `pytest --fixtures`. I do not have any idea why this happens or what causes this.

---

## Environment

- Python 3.7.3
- Pytest 4.4.0
- `pytest-django` 3.4.8
- Django 2.2

Comment: Add a `conftest.py` to your root dir with the line `pytest_plugins = ['myproject.testing.fixtures']`. `pytest_files` setting is for tests discovery, so while it also discovers fixtures, there's no guarantee that the fixture will be imported early enough to match the test arg.

Comment: Thanks, it seems this did the trick. Please provide it as an answer so that I can accept it as valid and Googlers also have clue about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have fixtures that should be kept in a separate module and accessible by the whole test suite, best is to register the module as a plugin to ensure it loads before the test collection phase. Create a file named `conftest.py` in the project root dir with the content

```
pytest_plugins = ['myproject.testing.fixtures']
```

Of course, you can just use the `conftest.py` instead of the `fixtures.py` and put the fixtures there.